# SCIP: How to find if a current value of a variable in the incumbent solution is integer or not?

Tags: scip

I am trying to go over over some variables during some branching and I want to know if the current solution has any variables that are integers.

I am doing this:

```
SCIPgetSolVal(scip, sol, (*transport_vars)[i][j])) > 0.999
```

But I want to know if there exists a method that can tell me that `(*transport_vars)[i][j]` is achieving its upper limit (binary 1.0) instead of comparing it to > 0.999.

In case it matters, I am comparing it with 0.999 in a constraint handler. I think I am facing numerical issues if I use 0.999

Answer (score 1):

You can just call `SCIPisIntegral(SCIP* scip, SCIP_Real val)` if you just want to know if your value is integer (within tolerances).
If you really want to know if it is 1 or not, you can use either `SCIPisEq` or `SCIPisFeasEq`. Both check equality with a tolerance. In the first case the tolerance is scips num_epsilon parameter and in the second it is the feasibility tolerance.

Comment: if the value us say 0.00000000001, does SCIPisIntegral return true? I mean I want to know if an edge is present between two customers, and sometimes SCIP gives values like 0.99999 as integer solution.

Comment: Yes, all these methods use tolerances. The default `num_epsolon` value of SCIP is `1e-9`, so SCIP will consider all values with absolute value less than `1e-9`  as `0` and all values with fractionality less than `1e-9` as integral.